# Bean or property class for managed bean cannot be found

Tags: jsf-2, jboss7.x

I'm trying to make a simple JSF hello world, with JSF 2.0, JBoss AS 7.0
Here's my xhml file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"> 

    <h:head>
        <title>Page 1</title>
    </h:head> 
    <body> 
        <f:view>
            <h:outputLabel value="Hello Stock Manager Hello JSF again" />
            <br/>
            <h:outputLabel value="Tester Bean : #{testerBean.message}" />
        </f:view>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

and here's the managed bean class :

```
package prv.stockmanager.web.beans;

public class TesterBean {

    private String message = "This is a message";

    public TesterBean() {
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

And here's the faces-config (which is in the web-inf) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
      <managed-bean>
       <managed-bean-name>testerBean</managed-bean-name>
       <managed-bean-class>prv.stockmanager.web.beans.TesterBean</managed-bean-class>
       <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
       <managed-property>  <property-name>message</property-name>
        <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
        <value/>
       </managed-property>
      </managed-bean>
     </faces-config>
```

The page works fine without exception if I remove the call to the managed bean. But when I call the managed bean I get this :

Bean or property class prv.stockmanager.web.beans.TesterBean for managed bean testerBean cannot be found.
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:265) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]

Is it because JBoss AS 7.0 is using JSF 2.1 jar file or something? Should I use JSF 2.1 then? How to change that?

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved, I figured out that Eclipse is not generating the class. I disabled the automatic build and it worked fine. There should be a problem with JBoss Studio that I am using.